# Add a xib file to a Swift Package

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I want to start using modular code with the new Swift Package Manager integration with Xcode 11.

The problem is that I can't seem to add any kind of UI files to my new package. I just need to add a xib file.

How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently Swift packages only support source code so you can't add a xib file to the package. Read the What's Missing? section in the following article:

[Creating Swift Packages in Xcode](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/creating-swift-packages-in-xcode/)

**UPDATE**

Xcode 12 allows you to add files that are not source code files to Swift packages. I have not created a Swift package so I cannot provide detailed instructions on how to add a xib file to a Swift package. But as @ffritz mentioned in a comment to this answer, Apple's documentation has an article on bundling resources in Swift packages.

[Bundling Resources with a Swift Package](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/bundling_resources_with_a_swift_package)

Comment: This is outdated. It is now possible to bundle resources like `xib` files and such, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/bundling_resources_with_a_swift_package.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Marks answer above and the Apple docs he shared, I was able to solve my problem with loading .xib files in my Swift Package. I will explain my steps here for future onlookers.

1. Move all of my .xib files in my new Swift package into a folder named Resources (in location `/Sources/PackageName/Resources`)
2. Change any code I have which loads these .xib files programatically to include the module bundle. E.g:

   ```
    super.init(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil) //Old way of initialising

    super.init(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: Bundle.module) //New way of initialising
   ```

Comment: Would you explain to care what is Bundle.module?

Comment: It's a accessor for the current module which is automatically generated for any package target that includes at least one resource.

Read here for more info: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650158

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Swift package with resources `Bundle` gains automatic static identifiers per package e.g a package called `Moon` would be accessed via `Bundle.moon`

e.g to instantiate a cell with a XIB called `Crater.xib` in `Moon` you would use

`let nib = UINib(nibName: "Crater", bundle: Bundle.moon)`