# Package.swift - where do copied resources go?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

Say I have a `Package.swift` with the following:

```
 targets: [
     .target(
         name: "SomeTarget",
         dependencies: [],
         path: "SomePath",
         resources: [.copy("../Assets")]
     )
 ]
```

And the `Assets` folder contains:

- myImage.png and
- myFile.xib

How can I access these files?

(There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67072316/127853) which references `Bundle.module`, but if I reference that, I get a `Type 'Bundle' has no member 'module'` error).

I've tried enumerating all the bundles searching for the xib:

```
    var targetBundle:Bundle
    let allBundles = Bundle.allBundles

    // Set as the first
    targetBundle = allBundles.first!

    for tempBundle in allBundles {
        if let path = tempBundle.path(forResource: "myFile", ofType: "xib")
        {
            if(path.lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8) > 0)
            {
                targetBundle = tempBundle
                break
            } // End of we found one
        }
        else if let path = tempBundle.path(forResource: "myFile", ofType: "nib")
        {
            if(path.lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8) > 0)
            {
                targetBundle = tempBundle
                break
            } // End of we found one
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't get found. If I open the .app package on the file system, I also cannot find the assets anywhere - I even extracted the Assets.car file in the main app bundle to see if they exist within that, but to no avail.

Where can I find these assets?

Comment: Apple's docs clearly say `Always use Bundle.module when you access resources. A package shouldn’t make assumptions about the exact location of a resource.` (here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/bundling_resources_with_a_swift_package). According to the same docs: `If a target includes resources, Xcode creates a resource bundle and an internal static extension on Bundle to access it for each module. `. So clearly in your case the package is not built right. So instead of trying to hack their location, figure out why Bundle.module is not generated

Comment: @thiscommunityistoxic but what if I'm trying to access the file from within the package itself? From what I understand, it does not get a bundle.module?

Comment: When I’ve gotten the error “Type 'Bundle' has no member 'module'” it has often been an issue with Xcode after doing some changes to the package, so cleaning the build folder and or the derived data folder has helped

Comment: Try `Bundle(identifier: "PackageName")`

Comment: I was only talking about internal access, as external requires few more steps... nother thought: how do you open your package in xcode? do you click on Package.swift (as you should), or trying to open xcodeproj?

Comment: The error appears when SPM cannot load your resources. In your case, this seems to be because you are accessing resources from a level up (../). I don't know why this is an issue with SPM, but I am facing the same problem. I have to use @Wode Liu's solution to get it to work...

Answer (score 2):

When a swift package has `resources`, and the resources is put in the right directory(which is in the **target** folder under **Sources** folder), SPM will automatically create a `resource_bundle_accessor.swift` after building and add it to the module. The file adds a static `module` properly for `Bundle`, you can actually find the file in `DerivedSources`.
If you get the no module error, moving your resource folder to the right position will probably fix it. In your case, change resources in `Package.swift` to `.copy("Assets")`, and put `Assets` under `Sources/SomeTarget`.